# Elisp defadvice around clarification

Tags: elisp

[Documentation for defadvice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Advice.html#Defining-Advice) says:

```
around-advice is wrapped around the execution of the function
```

This explanation is not clear to me. So I decided to test, how it works, using this code:

```
(defun fun ()
  (message "hi"))

(fun)

(defadvice fun (around around-fun activate)
  (message "3"))

(fun)
```

Output:

```
hi
3
```

What is happening here? Why don't I see "hi" message after the advice is defined? Is function executed at all? Or the code, defined in advice is executed instead of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Around means that the advice is executed *instead* of the function.
You can still call the original with `ad-do-it`.
See [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Around_002dAdvice.html)

Just to add a small example:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (* 2 x))

(defadvice foo (around bar activate)
  (setq ad-return-value
        (if (= x 1)
            42
          (+ 1 ad-do-it))))

(foo 1)
;; 42
(foo 2)
;; 5
(foo 3)
;; 7
```